# How to stop websocket.WebSocketApp logs being generated

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket

I am using the `websocket.WebSocketApp` to send and receive messages on `websocket`.
I am able to run the application and can send and receive messages.

but wherever I received or send any message many logs are getting generated as shown below.

```
++Sent raw: b'\x82\xfe\x05X\x'
++Rcv raw: b'\x81p my message'
++Sent decoded: fin=1 opcode=2 data=b'fn5+fn5+fn5+fn5+fn5'
++Rcv decoded: fin=1 opcode=1 data=b'my message'
++Sent raw: b'\x82\xfe\x05XQa\xab\x0f~\x17\x9c$~'
++Sent raw: b
```

How can I stop these logs being generated?
These logs are from websockt library

Comment: `websocket.enableTrace(True)` should do it. you can read more about it [here](https://websocket-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html#debug-and-logging-options)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing False to enableTrace stopped all the trace level logs.

```
websocket.enableTrace(False)
```

Thank you @Jyotirmay for you comment